# Faceook- "GraphQL query is unauthorized. This query is unauthorized because some field's permission check has failed."

Tags: facebook

Got this a while ago re Facebook. Googled it as how to fix it, but I am "Technically Challenged," and don't understand what to do. "GraphQL query is unauthorized. This query is unauthorized because some field's permission check has failed."

Reviewed posts, but did not see a solution.

Reloaded. Will sign out and sign in again and see what happens.

Confused about what to "tag." Will have to "tag" something for this post to go thru.